# HP Envy x360 - Juno installation attempt => black screen and freeze

Tags: hp

I own a HP Envy x360 15 inch and i cannot get Elementary OS Juno to install at all. I get into the menu which asks me to try it before install; Install it or install as a manufacturer. I am completely new to Linux and i wish to try eOS as windows is not interesting to me any more, i do not intend on spending 5 hours a day troubleshooting, so if that is too much to ask for, i apologize for bothering you.

After pressing either it tells me a list of sentences for 1 second and i managed to take a picture of the machines disabilities. [image]

Comment: I got it installed and it had a low resolution and unknown display, so i went to amd to get a driver for my ryzen 5 2500U and after that, the resolution went even lower. I do not even know if i managed to install it. I just pressed the install file and a yellow page popped up with a lot of text, so i assumed it had installed itself. I tried to fix the low resolution by surfing the web endlessly trying many tips, nothing helped. I then resorted to try a clean re-install of eOS, but to my surprise, the previous install apparently f***ed up my laptop so that it does not register my usb stick. I c

Comment: press Esc or any fuction key when you boot so that you can see the firmware/bios and you can set the boot option to the usb stick.

Answer (score 1):

Boot your laptop, when the grub menu appears press e.

It will show a lot of text, look for the words `quiet splash` and add `nomodeset` between them. Like this: `quiet nomodeset splash`. Press F10 and it'll boot.

Now you need to go into AppCenter and Install the graphic driver from the Updates tab. You can also execute `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` if you prefer working from the terminal.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much 

Comment: Hey I've updated my question since I said something wrong. nomodeset is just for the first boot, then you need to install the driver and it will work normally on the next boot.

Answer (score 0):

Manually there is no drivers to be found as shown in picture. But thank you a bunch man

I would love for the OS to work.

My processor is Ryzen 2500u. Any hope to solve it? I do not even know how to install stuff. I have tried many guides, but it doesnt seem to work. Is it really a big process just to download and install an app from the app center? I hoped it would be a bit like android.